# .htaccess 301 redirect from old url to SEO friendly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have link like this:

```
www.site.com/page.php?p=1
```

Need to rewrite it to friendly URLs in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^home$ page.php?p=1
```

It works but now I have two active links with the same content.

Tried to add 301 redirect from old link to new but stuck in loop. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Your rule is looking for `home` and redirecting to `page.php?p=1`- that doesn't seem like the intended behavior. I think a little more detail would help. Can you give an example of the url you want to redirect from and to? You said "ried to add 301 redirect from old link to new but stuck in loop." Where did you do the redirect?

Comment: On site I have link `www.site.com/page.php?p=1` but I want to change it to something more friendly for users like `www.site.com/home`. So first I have to do rewrite (and it works, `www.site.com/home` - display the same content as `www.site.com/page.php?p=1`), and after this add redirect rules so when someone who have old link bookmarked will be redirected to new, friendly URL.
All have to be done in .htaccess, can't change URL generation in app.

Tried to do this using example from [link](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/6079.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try matching against the actual request so that your rules won't loop:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /page\.php\?p=1(&|\ |^)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /home?%3 [L,R=301]

# then your internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^home$ page.php?p=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the redirect on the page and handle it in the htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php\?p=1$ /home [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect to /home and stop the redirect loop you have now.

Answer (score 0):

another quick & dirty way to prevent looping in these situations i've found is to add a querystring and then check for its existence in the redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !foo=bar
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /home [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ page.php?p=1&foo=bar [NC,L]
```

found on this site: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/542-how-to-properly-redirect-for-maximum-seo/

Answer (score -1):

> Redirect 301 /page.php?p=1 www.yourwebsite.com/home?p=1 RewriteRule
>   ^home?p=1$ /page.php?p=1